# Translation of "Back" text in the iphone template

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, inline-translations

I am not able to find the place to translate "Back" Button text in the Iphone template. I tried translation in few .csv files but it didn't work. Looking for help to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the string "Back" in the iphone.js!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, locate the template/s where the string is being printed in your project

Then, be sure it is something like this variations (this allows translations)

```
<?php echo $this->__('Back'); ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('XXXX')->__('Back'); ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('XXXX')->__('Back'); ?>
```

And not just (this don't allow translations)

```
<?php echo 'Back'; ?>
```

If your template/s use the `__()` function (allowing translations), then the .csv in **app/locale** folder should work. Maybe you are editing the wrong file, or maybe you have some syntax error in the .csv file (some quotes bad placed, or something like that)

Comment: Yes thanks for replay. My Problem I can't locate the string. I searched in all folders. I used the path hints. But I found nothing.

Comment: That is the code:<div class="button-wrap"><button class="previous-category">Back</button></div>